¿CÓMO EVITO PERDER LA REFERENCIA DE UN OBJETO PASADO ENTRE FUNCIONES?
Estoy trabajando con Node js y este json respuesta de una API, tiene el siguiente esquema:
{
   "data": [
     {
       "id": 1234
       "name": "stackoverlow"
       "images": [{
         "url1": "https://servidor-de-imagenes.com/url1/1234.jpg"
         "url2": "https://servidor-de-imagenes.com/url2/1234.jpg"
         "url3": "https://servidor-de-imagenes.com/url3/1234.jpg"
       }]
     },
     { otro-objeto},
     { otro },
     //* y así sucesivamente */
  ]
}

Estoy descargando las imágenes de la llave: images y una vez almacenadas en disco, quiero cambiar las url como valores de la propiedad images por la ruta en donde se almacenó cada imagen pero en algún momento de la pila de llamadas de mis funciones pierdo la referencia al objeto (json.parse()) original y se comienza a pasar una copia ( no se guardan los cambios de las rutas "C:\Users\usuario\Documents...." )
Esto es lo que tengo:
try {
  const json = await axios.get("https://www.api-de-prueba.com/...");
  const imgJson = await extraerPropiedadesQueMeInteresan(json);

  json.data.forEach(async(_, index)=>{
    await fetchImagesDeCadaObjeto(imgJson, index);
  });

  /* escribir imgJson en disco */
} catch {}



  const fetchImagesDeCadaObjeto = async(imgJson, index)=>{
    const { id } = imgJson.data[index];
    const uris = [
      { "url": imgJson.data[index].images[0]["url1"], "img_key": "url1" },
      { "url": imgJson.data[index].images[0]["url2"], "img_key": "url2" },
      { "url": imgJson.data[index].images[0]["url3"], "img_key": "url3" },
    ];

    const args = {
      "jsonImgs": imgJson,
      "index": index
    };
    const limiter = Bottleneck({ minTime: 1000, maxConcurrent: 2 });
    const descargarCadaImagenConLimiter = limiter.wrap(descargarCadaImagen);


    /* EXACTAMENTE AL ENTRAR AQUI PIERDO LA REFERENCIA A imgJson DENTRO DE args */
    uris.forEach(({url, img_key})=>{
      try {
        args.img_key = img_key;
        await descargarCadaImagenConLimiter(args, url, id, img_key);
      } catch {}
    });
  };


const descargarCadaImagen = async(args, url, id, img_key)=>{
  try {
    try {
      await axios.get(url/* DESCARGAR LA IMAGEN */);
      var path = fileSystem.join(id, img_key/* HACER EL PATH CON LA FORMA: C:\\...1234_url1.jpg */);
    } catch {}

    args["rutaCadaImagen"] = path;
    await Promise.all([
      /* ESCRIBIR IMAGEN EN DISCO */
      /* const { jsonImgs, index, img_key, rutaCadaImagen } = args */
      /* REPLAZAR LA URL POR EL PATH: jsonImgs.data.[index].images[img_key] = rutCadaImagen */
    ]);
  } catch {}
  
};


Lo que está ocurriendo en tu código es una pérdida de referencia porque estás intentando dar un nuevo valor a una variable que ya referenciaba el objeto original.
Esa reasignación hace que la variable apunte a una nueva copia del objeto y pierda la referencia.
uris.forEach(({url, img_key}) => {
  try {
    args.img_key = img_key; // Aquí cambias `args.img_key`
    await descargarCadaImagenConLimiter(args, url, id, img_key); // El mismo `args` se pasa en cada iteración
  } catch {}
});

En esa parte, el objeto args está compartiendo la misma referencia.
Cada vez que se ejecuta el bucle forEach, la propiedad img_key en el objeto args se modifica. Como el bucle es asíncrono (await),   las iteraciones ocurren simultáneamente, lo que causa conflictos.
Una solución sería hacer una copia superficial de args, garantizando que cada iteración tenga su propia copia. De esta forma, cada ejecución asíncrona en el forEach tendrá su propio conjunto de datos, evitando conflictos de referencias compartidas.
uris.forEach(async ({url, img_key}) => {
  try {
   
    const argsCopia = { ...args, img_key }; 

    await descargarCadaImagenConLimiter(argsCopia, url, id, img_key);
  } catch {}
});

o también de esta forma:
uris.forEach(async ({url, img_key}) => {
  try {
    const argsCopia = { ...args }; 
    argsCopia.img_key = img_key;   
    await descargarCadaImagenConLimiter(argsCopia, url, id, img_key); 
  } catch {}
});


Lo intenté, no ocurre nada, no reemplaza la url con la ruta al escribir en disco. no sé si es porque la escritura es una tarea asíncrona también pero debería de esperar a que el forEach principal que llama a la función fetchImagesDeCadaObjeto() termine.

Intentó implementar la función callback, en ese caso el control de flujo también sería asíncrono.
